# Updating a table using values in previous rows and then using the outputted value in the next calculation

Tags: sql, postgresql, forecasting

| Month | Value | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| June | 400 | 50 | 20 |
| July | NULL | 25 | 10 |
| August | NULL | 50 | 20 |

I want to forecast future months using existing values.

I need to update the NULL values for July using the calculation 400 + 50 - 20 and obtain the value 430.
I then need to use July's value of 430 in a calculation (430 + 25 - 10) which should return a value of 445 for August.

How can I used postgreSQL to fill these the value column for each month given columns a and b and an initial value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a query, you can use:

```
select t.*,
       ( sum(value) over () +
         sum(a + b) over (order by month) - (a + b)
       ) as imputed_value
from t;
```

Note:  This assumes that `month` is really stored in some manner that preserves the date -- such as the first day of the month. If it is a string, you can use:

```
select t.*,
       ( sum(value) over () +
         sum(a + b) over (order by to_date(month, 'Mon')) - (a + b)
       ) as imputed_value
from t;
```

Comment: Amazing this has sorted my problem, thank you for your help!